# dynamics CRM online のプラグイン登録方法がわかりません。

Tags: visual-studio

現在dynamicsCRM onlineを使用しているのですが、pluginの登録方法がわからず困っています。

これまでに試みたことは
・Visual Studioのインストールおよびpluginコードのビルド
・dynamicsCRM SDKのインストール
です。

SDK\Tools\PluginRegistration
に保存されているPluginRegistration.exeを開きメニューバーのcreateNewConnectionを
押した時に表示されるログイン画面で、ログイン出来ずに止まっています。

ここではdynamics CRM serverのログイン情報が必要なのでしょうか？
もしそうなら、新しくdynamics CRM serverをローカルにインストールする必要があるのでしょうか。

ご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

CRMのSDK2016で試してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: SDK2016でどのように解決するのか、具体的に書いてください。

Comment: SDK2015の英語版で実行できました。